# How to extract and append the list(as dict values) from python dictionary to a list having an list of dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, iteration

Here z is a list of dict().

```
z = [{'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},
     {'loss': [1, 2, 2] , 'val_loss':[2,4,5], 'accuracy':[3,8,9], 'val_accuracy':[5,9,7]},]
```

I want to append all dictionary values of 'loss' in a separate list and similarly 'val_loss', 'accuracy', 'val_accuracy'.
For that, I tried to write the below python code:

```
a = b = c = d = []
for lis in z:
  a.append(lis['loss'])
  b.append(lis['val_loss'])
  c.append(lis['accuracy'])
  d.append(lis['val_accuracy'])
```

But when I am trying to print the length of the list `print(len(a))` the output is 40 instead of 10?

I just want to append all `'loss'` into `a`.

Comment: Your issue is you are assigning all variables to the same list, so appending to one appends to all of them.
This is demonstrated here:
`
>>> a = b = [] >>> a.append(1) >>> print(b) >>> [1]
`
Initialize them separately.

Comment: To add to what @CoryNezin said, you could write ```a, b, c, d = [], [], [], []``` as assignment

Comment: @CoryNezin, thanx... I was making the mistake by initializing all at one. This  >>> a = []
 >>> b = []
 >>> c = []
 >>> d = []  resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The notation `a = b = c = d = []` assign a new list to `d`, then assign the 3 others variable to `d`, so you have 4 variables pointing to one same list, so you put 4*10 items in the same list.

Do :

```
a, b, c, d = [], [], [], []
```

Using `map` and `itemgetter` you can do

```
from operator import itemgetter
loss =         list(map(itemgetter("loss"), z))
val_loss =     list(map(itemgetter("val_loss"), z))
accuracy =     list(map(itemgetter("accuracy"), z))
val_accuracy = list(map(itemgetter("val_accuracy"), z))
```

Comment: please include the appropriate imports for itemgetter

Comment: need to include this `from operator import itemgetter`

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you create a variable, you are just creating a pointer to an object, and not a copy of the object. In this case, when you are initializing your list with `a = b = c = d = []`, you are actually making a, b, c, and d point to the same list instead of creating four different lists.

Take the following example:

```
In [1]: a = b = c = d = []                                                      

In [2]: a.append("a")                                                           

In [3]: b                                                                       
Out[3]: ['a']
```

What you actually need to do is initialize four different lists:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
for lis in z:
  a.append(lis['loss'])
  b.append(lis['val_loss'])
  c.append(lis['accuracy'])
  d.append(lis['val_accuracy'])
```